# Java MVC Communication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So I am pretty new to Spring and the whole MVC structure. Currently we work with tomcat server and another layer that we call a "service" layer. I am confused on how the tomcat layer communicates with the service layer.

So for example: Lets say I am validating passwords for users. So the idea would be that it would first be validated on the UI side aka the tomcat side via javascript and after that these values would pass over to the service layer where the most of the back-end logic lies and the values would be validated by Java. So my question is how exactly are these values passed from the UI end to the back-end layer?

Comment: I recommend performing a few of these transactions (e.g., logging in or changing password or whatever you're doing) in the browser with the Network tab open and examining the requests and responses between the browser and the server.

Comment: Yeah but I think we only get the ones on tomcat and not the backend. Hence why i was curious on how exactly it all works.

Comment: You seem to be needing to understand some fundamental concepts about the stack, so I'd direct you to [the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html) while noting that requests for off-site resources (as in your new edit) are explicitly off-topic for SO.

Comment: Gotcha, removed the last sentence. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This would be good start for you: [Spring: Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

Once you have a backend service created, your frontend will call the service as a REST endpoint, values will be passed as GET or POST request with the request to this backend service

Comment: Ok thanks. But currently we run the tomcat layer on one IntelliJ instance and the backend on another IntelliJ instance, so it basically works the same way as above correct?